# Issues when i integrate google sign in option to my application in android studio 1.2.2

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, android-library, google-api-client

I got some issues in the google sign option integration.

I am using android studio 1.2.2 and i follow the link 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

but got error in manifest file

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

At `@integer/google_play_services_version` as red color says Cannot resolve symbol issue.

**Additional information**

Added this to my  projects build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

and this to module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle build successfully

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution ,

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    }
```

Adding this has solve that issues.
I don't know why its not mentioned in the googles document

**Some more information about the issues**

In the document they have mentioned the followings

> The Google Services plugin for Gradle parses configuration information
>   from the google-services.json file. Add the plugin to your project by
>   updating your top-level build.gradle and your app-level build.gradle
>   files as follows:

I have added the googel-services.json in my project route folder as described in the document, but its not add any library to my application until i add the  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` to my module.